# Dependent Drop down list Jquery, AJAX, PHP, MYSQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to create a dependent drop down list but it doesnt seem to be populating after I make my first selection. Each selection will get data from a `MySQL` database. In order for the second drop down to have any options (other then a default "select option" value) the user would have to first make a selection on the first drop down After a lot of googling I am having a hard time finding a simple solution to this.

Here is what I have so far,

**Drop down lists** (I use `PHP` and `MySQL` here to generate and output the drop down lists in a `getter.php` and `require_once` into an `index.php` and `echo` out the drop down)

```
$accountOptions = "";
$facilityOptions = "";

$dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);        
if (!$dbc) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

///ACCOUNTS/////
$accountQuery = "SELECT account_id, account_name FROM account";
$accountData = mysqli_query($dbc, $accountQuery);

//loop through data and display all accounts
while ($aRow = mysqli_fetch_array($accountData)) {
         $accountOptions .="<option value=\"".$aRow['account_id']."\">" . $aRow['account_name'] . "</option>";
}

$accountDropDown=" <label>Accounts: </label><br>
                    <select name='account' id='account' onChange='getFacility(this.value)'>
                        <option selected='selected' disabled='disabled' value=''>Select account</option>
                    " . $accountOptions . "
                    </select>";

////FACILITIES/////
$facilityDropDown=" <label>Facility: </label><br>
                    <select name='facility' id='facility'>
                        <option selected='selected' disabled='disabled' value=''>Select facility</option>
                    </select>";
```

**JQuery/AJAX**

```
function getFacility(val) {
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "getfacility.php",
        data:'account_id='+val,

        success: function(data){
                $("#facility").html(data);
        }
        });
    }
```

**getfacility.php**

```
//db connection..


if(!empty($_POST["account_id"])) {

$accountID = $_POST['account_id'];

$sql = "SELECT *, account.account_name FROM facility "
     . "INNER JOIN account ON account.account_id = facility.account_id "
     . "WHERE facility.account_id = '". $accountID ."'";

$data = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);

echo "<option selected='selected' disabled='disabled' value=''>Select facility</option>";

while ($fRow = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
     $facilityOptions .="<option value=\"".$fRow['facility_id']."\">" . $fRow['facility_name'] . "</option>";
}

    $facilityDropDown=" <label>Facility: </label><br>
                <select name='facility' id='facility'>
                    <option selected='selected' disabled='disabled' value=''>Select facility</option>
                " . $facilityOptions . "
                </select>";
}
```

Right now, when I make a selection on my first drop down, the second one does not populate with anything, where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the changes in **getfacility.php**,

if your ajax showing 200 ok status and expected response in Network (Console)

```
//db connection..


if(!empty($_POST["account_id"])) {

$accountID = $_POST['account_id'];

$sql = "SELECT *, account.account_name FROM facility "
     . "INNER JOIN account ON account.account_id = facility.account_id "
     . "WHERE facility.account_id = '". $accountID ."'";

$data = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);

echo "<option selected='selected' disabled='disabled' value=''>Select facility</option>";

while ($fRow = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
     echo "<option value=\"".$fRow['account_id']."\">" . $fRow['account_name'] . "</option>";
}
```

Comment: I changed getfacility.php accordingly and I checked under the Network tab in the console and I am getting the "200 OK" status.

Comment: Nice, then check in "Network -> (Click on file) -> Response tab" your expected data is loaded or not?

Comment: It is outputting only this "<option selected='selected' disabled='disabled' value=''>Select facility</option>"

Comment: it's means your SQL query not fetching data or no record for this condition

Comment: I just double checked and `echo`'d out the SQL query and it is working properly, and the only reason it is outputting the `<option>` tag is because I am `echo`'ing it out.

Comment: My mistake, I hadn't noticed that in the while statement you had turned that into an `echo`. Working now, thanks for the help!!